# Django models - object.get() not working properly - Exception:DoesNotExist:

Tags: python, mysql, django

Django is very new to me (first day) and I'm working on someone's daily stats script which uses Django's db ORM to access MySQL and does some stats.

Here is the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shengye/stats/offerwall_daily_report/lib/offerwall_daily_report.py", line 163, in __getSummaryRenderByChannel
    channel = channel, display_type = DISPLAY_TYPE_NORMAL)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 151, in get
        return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 307, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name)
db.models.DoesNotExist: OwStatsDailySummary matching query does not exist.
```

Here is the code that might have gone wrong:

```py
        sT = OwStatsDailySummary.objects.get(dt = self.__cfg.dt,
            channel = channel, display_type = DISPLAY_TYPE_NORMAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, aparently th problem is the matching query does not exist in the DB yet. So I am just going to update the DB first. I hope this will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use Django Exceptions `DoesNotExist`

```
try:
    sT = OwStatsDailySummary.objects.get(dt = self.__cfg.dt,
        channel = channel, display_type = DISPLAY_TYPE_NORMAL)
except DoesNotExist:
    # Create your object here
```